# json_encode replace specific string for a number (for flot.js)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, flot

Hi I've searched extensively for this and have tweaked in many ways but I just can't get it right.

My goal is to retrieve mysql data from a feedback form and plot a flot.js chart. So far I can retrieve the data with this:

```
$query = "SELECT flavor,  COUNT(flavor) FROM $tbl_name GROUP BY flavor";
$result = mysql_query($query);  

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$dataset1[] = array($rows['flavor'],$rows['COUNT(flavor)']);
}
```

This retrieves flavor rating (excellent, good, average or bad) and counts how many times each have been used in the feedback and the array looks like this:

```
[["average","1"],["bad","1"],["excellent","1"],["good","2"]]
```

flot.js needs my x,y values to be numbers so I've managed to change the numeric value to an integer by using JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK when I call $dataset1 so now it looks like this:

```
[["average",1],["bad",1],["excellent",1],["good",2]]
```

I can't figure out how to convert the words "excellent, good, average and bad" to simple numeric values like: the word "excellent" should be 1, "good" should be 2 and so on, so my flot data outputs like:

```
[[3,1],[4,1],[1,1],[2,2]]
```

Here's my flot javascript:

```
$(function () {

$.plot(
   $("#graph"),
   [
    {
      label: "Flavor",
      data: <?php echo json_encode($dataset1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>,
      bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 0.5,
        align: "center"
      }   
    }
 ],
 {
   xaxis: {
     ticks: [
       [1, "excellent"],
       [2, "good"],
       [3, "average"],
       [4, "bad"]
     ]
   }   
 }
);
```

});

Has anyone run into something like this? Am I approaching it the wrong way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've also researched a lot to try not to double post, please forgive me if this has been answered already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the value before you append to your array...

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    switch ($rows['flavor']) {
        case 'excellent':
            $number = 1;
            break;
        case 'good':
            $number = 2;
            break;
        case 'average':
            $number = 3;
            break;
        case 'bad':
            $number = 4;
    }
    $dataset1[] = array($number, $rows['COUNT(flavor)']);
}
```

Comment: Hi Gordon I appreciate the help, but still flot.js would need the words "excellent", "average", "good" and "bad" to be numbers instead of words. 
I'm trying to wrap my head around sprintf, can it be used to apply a specific number to each word?

Comment: So, color me confused... Are you saying that you actually need your JSON to be like so... `[[3, 1],[4, 1],[1, 1],[2, 2]]`?

Comment: yes I'm actually trying to replace the words for a number. Sorry for the confusion, I'm reading my question and I can see how I mixed everything up myself.  Right now I'm trying to loop through the array to find and replace "excellent" with 1 and so on.

Comment: @Diego Okay... let's try this again. See my complete rewrite! :)

Comment: And yes I see now that I phrased my question wrong, sorry, it was late at night, json_encode probably has nothing to do with my problem and I should be looping either in php or jquery

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't what you think it is; `json_encode()` tries to do the right thing by preserving the original PHP data type, and the data coming out of your MySQL database is strings.

Want numbers? Find this bit:

```
$dataset1[] = array($rows['flavor'],$rows['COUNT(flavor)']);
```

and change it to this:

```
$dataset1[] = array($rows['flavor'],(int)$rows['COUNT(flavor)']);
```

Comment: Thank you very kindly but my COUNT(flavor) part was already an integer by using JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK in my json_encode bit.
I actually needed to convert "excellent" to 1, "good" to 2, "average" to 3, and "bad" to 4. So that flot.js would recognize both $rows as numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better just sort it out in the javascript that way your are not hard-coding your `flavors to integers` mapping in two locations:

```
dataForFlot = [];
ticksForFlot = [];

flavorToIntMap = {'excellent':1, 'good':2, 'average':3, 'bad':4}; // this is our data to tick mapping
originalData = [["average",1],["bad",1],["excellent",1],["good",2]]; // from your PHP

$.each(originalData, function(){ dataForFlot.push([flavorToIntMap[this[0]],this[1]]);});// convert the data to how flot wants it
$.each(flavorToIntMap, function(k,v){ticksForFlot.push([v,k]);}); // convert our mapping to the how flot wants the ticks
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, I had already implemented the php switch when I saw this, but I'm certain it'll prove helpful for future reference.